# Regex for assuring that string doesn't have cyrillic (or latin) characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a company name field in my app.
The company might be Russian or from any other country.

If the company is Russian I need to restrict user input so that he can type any chars except latin letters.

If the company is not Russian then I need to restrict user input so that he can type any chars except Russian.

So I actually have such regexps:

```
latinChars: /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s-]*$/
cyrillicChars: /^[а-яА-Яё][а-яА-Яё\s-]*$/
```

But I cannot figure out how to exclude characters. Like, I tried using `(?!...)` operator without success.

Comment: Exclude is NOT include. How you check included charaters? Use that condition with negative `!` for check characters excluded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `[^]` operator to match anything except what's enclosed in it.

Example :

```
^[^A-Za-z]*$
```

Will match anything except all latin letters.

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/adIApd/2).

You can apply this to the range of Russian chars.